# Laravel JSON Pagination: How to remove the arrows from next/previous link?

Tags: laravel

I'm using Laravel `8.20.1` and my API route returns a paginated JSON response.

Is there a better way than `str_replace()` to remove the arrows from the labels?

`routes/api.php`:

```php
Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->get('/items', function (Request $request) {
  return new ItemCollection(Item::paginate(5));
});
```

**response.data.meta**

```
{
    "current_page": 1,
    "from": 1,
    "last_page": 3,
    "links": [
        {
            "url": null,
            "label": "&laquo; Previous",
            "active": false
        },
        ....
        {
            "url": "http://localhost/api/items?page=2",
            "label": "Next &raquo;",
            "active": false
        }
    ],
    "path": "http://localhost/api/items",
    "per_page": 5,
    "to": 5,
    "total": 15
}
```

Comment: That doesn't look like the default response. Are you using some different library or transformer? https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/pagination#converting-results-to-json

Comment: I've updated the response that I get. I'm requesting the data using "axios". I'm not using the pagination views. Maybe I'm missing something...

Comment: Can you include your API code? I.e. the code being called by your `axios()` request. Might be worthwhile to see how you're fetching and returning data. Do you use something like `return request()->json(Model::paginate())` (or some derivative)?

Comment: `Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->get('/items', function (Request $request) {
    return new ItemCollection(Item::paginate(5));
});`

Comment: Thanks, but next time, please edit your question with that information; it's easier to read when properly formatted (I've done this for you for now)

Comment: Still fairly baffling. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-resources#data-wrapping-and-pagination indicates a very different format for collection responses. You're certain you're not using something like Dingo?

Comment: No, I've just added the route and used `artisan` to create the `items` resource collection.

Comment: It looks like you used simplePaginate() instead of paginate()...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those labels for Next and Previous are in the translation files, `resources/lang/en/pagination.php`. If you look at `Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator::linkCollection` you can see it building the links part of the response.